# Does $\sum _{ n=1 }^\infty \frac {(-1) ^n} n \sin (nx) $ converge uniformly on $[0, \pi )$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

i tried Werierstrass M test, but >$$\left| \frac{(-1)^n}n \sin(nx)\right| \leq \frac 1 n.$$
is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel.27s_uniform_convergence_test

Comment: From a plot of a partial sum, it looks like this is the Fourier series of $C x, -\pi < x < \pi$ for some $C$.  If so, since the periodic continuation of the function is discontinuous, the Fourier series would have to exhibit the Gibbs phenomenon, and it wouldn't converge uniformly.

Comment: @DanielSchepler it is indeed the Fourier series of $-x,-\pi<x<\pi$.

Comment: I think it's actually the Fourier series of $-\frac{1}{2} x$.

Comment: The series converges to $0$ for $x=\pi$ so if we have uniform convergence this would imply that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=\pi$. You should be able to compute $\lim_{N\to\infty}[S_N(x_N) - S_N(y_N)] \not= 0$ as a Riemann sum when $x_N = \pi$, $x_N-y_N = \frac{c}{N}$ and $c>0$ giving you a contradiction.

Comment: @Winther: correct and elegant, you should write an answer!

Comment: I don't want to duplicate the question, however I would like to know whether uniformally convergent and differentiable fo x in $\ (0, \infty) $ ?

Answer (score 3):

It does not converge uniformly on the given interval: loosely speaking, the coefficients $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ do not decay fast enough to zero to ensure uniform convergence. The fact that $\{(-1)^n\sin(nx)\}_{n\geq 1}$ has bounded partial sums ensures that the given Fourier (sine) series is pointwise convergent on $(-\pi,\pi)$, so on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\pi\mathbb{Z}$ we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(nx) = W(x) \tag{1}$$
with $W(x)$ being a $2\pi$-periodic function equal to $\frac{x}{2}$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$, i.e. a [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave).
This function is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and that leads to [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon), contradicting uniform convergence. In a quantitative form,

$$\lim_{N\to +\infty}\sup_{x\in(-\pi,\pi)}\left|\frac{x}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}(-1)^{n+1}\right| = C > 0\tag{2}$$
and that can be proved, for instance, by showing that $\frac{x}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}(-1)^{n+1}$ has constant sign in a left neighbourhood of $\pi$ with size $\approx\frac{\pi}{N}$ and 
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\frac{x}{2}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}(-1)^{n+1}\right|^2\,dx =\pi\sum_{n>N}\frac{1}{n^2}\approx\frac{\pi}{N},\tag{3}$$
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}=\lim_{x\to \pi^-}\frac{x}{2}\neq \lim_{N\to +\infty}\lim_{x\to \pi^-}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}(-1)^{n+1}=0.\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

The series converges to $0$ for $x=\pi$ so if we assume the convergence is uniform on $[0,\pi)$ then the convergence is uniform on $[0,\pi]$ and in particular $f$ has to be continuous at $x=\pi$. Take $x = \pi$ and $x_N = \pi - \frac{c}{N}$ for some $c>0$ and consider the series of partial sums

$$f_N(x) - f_N(x_N) = \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{n}2\sin\left(\frac{nx-nx_N}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{nx+nx_N}{2}\right) \\= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{2}{\frac{n}{N}}\sin\left(\frac{cn}{2N}\right)\cos\left(\frac{cn}{2N}\right) = \frac{c}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\text{sinc}\left(\frac{cn}{N}\right)$$
This is a Riemann sum so we have
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}[f_N(x) - f_N(x_N)] = \int_0^c\text{sinc}(t){\rm d}t \not= 0$$
even though $x_N\to x$ contradicting uniform convergence.

Comment: how does uniform convergence on [0,pi] follow from uniform convergence on [0,pi)?

Comment: @bbw See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140519/converge-uniformly-on-open-interval-implies-on-closed-interval

Comment: does $sinc (\frac{cn}{N})$ mean $sin (c \cdot \frac{cn}{N})$?

Comment: @bbw [$\text{sinc}(x) \equiv \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html)