# Convergence of $\sum_{1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n}$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

How can we prove the convergence of following series, for each $\theta$, by *elementary* means?
$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n}$$

The series appears as the Fourier series for $f(\theta)=\theta$ considered over $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Note: The series converges for each $\theta$ (however, not uniformly in $\theta$) because it is indeed the Fourier transform of the [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave). See here for a previous detailed answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330395/does-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1-n-n-sin-nx-converge-uniformly-on and explanation. But probably this is a non-elementary proof?

Comment: Michael Penn does a good video on this problem.  The proof for convergence uses Dirichlet's test, which is not typically taught in a calculus course.  But actually computing the sum utilizes basic calculus techiniques. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXQNHqr1soo).