# Consider $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}$. Does it converges uniformly in the intervals $-1<x<1$ and $-1\le x\le 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> Consider the geometric series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{2n}$. Does it converges uniformly in the intervals $-1<x<1$ and $-1\le x\le 1$?
>
> The answer of the book says **no** in $-1<x<1.$

- My argument to justify the no convergence in $[-1, 1]$:

We have to show that $\max\limits_{-1\le x\le1} \Big|f(x)-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)\Big| \to 0$ when $n\to\infty$ (which is the definition for $[-1,1]$) doesn't hold.

The series has ratio $-x^2$, thus the $n$-th partial sum is $S_n=\frac{1-(-x^2)^{n+1}}{1+x^2}$.

And $\max\limits_{-1\le x\le1}\Big|f(x)-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)\Big|=\max\limits_{-1\le x\le1}\Big|\frac{-(-x^2)^{n+1}}{1+x^2}\Big|\not\to  0$ when $n\to\infty$ (justification is $n$-th term test).

Hence does not converge uniformly in $[-1,1]$

- Note that we cannot even consider convergence in $(-1,1)$ since the definition only applies for closed intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $[-1, 1]$, you're correct. For $x = 1$, the $\max$ does not go to $0$.

However, for $(-1, 1)$, I don't think the definition for uniform convergence requires closed intervals. You can indeed speak meaningfully about uniform convergence on open-intervals, like in [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140519/converge-uniformly-on-open-interval-implies-on-closed-interval).

Comment: I saw the definition in a book Partial Differential Equations by Strauss. Chapter 5, page 126

Comment: Maybe the author will use closed intervals whenever s/he means to use uniform convergence. But in general there is no such restriction, afaik.

Comment: Yes maybe. Although if that's the case then the exercise doesn't have much sense.

Comment: The exercise is fine. You're just wrong, @Bellatrix. Replace the argument you already gave with $\max_{-1\le x\le 1}$ with $\sup_{-1<x<1}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin but in the book was $\max\limits_{a\le x\le b}|...| $ as the definition

Comment: That obviously only applies to the closed interval $[a,b]$. The definition that is well-known is that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on a domain $E$ if, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N$ so that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ and for all $x\in E$. This means that $\sup_{x\in E} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.

Comment: @TedShifrin ok, thanks